# MS SQL 2005 Auto Increment Error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

So, I have tried to create a table inside my database 'Test',

```
CREATE TABLE TestTbl(
id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Agent_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
```

After it was created, I tried to add 2 values for the agent via php, but the result is this:

```
id | Agent_id
0     8080
0     8081
```

It does not auto increment, even if I set 'id' as a Primary key, still the problem occurs, anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Here is my insert statement in php, nevermind the `$conn`, because it works, it is for my sql connection

```
 if(isset($_POST['agentid'])){
    $agent = $_POST['agentid'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM [Test].[dbo].[TestTbl] WHERE [Agent_id] = '$agent'";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
      if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) !=0){
    echo "ID EXISTS";
       }else{
    $sql = "SET INDENTITY_INSERT TestTbl ON
    INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[TestTbl]
    ([id],[Agent_id]) VALUES ('','$agent')
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT TestTbl OFF";
    echo "Added";
    }}
```

Comment: What is your complete insert statement?

Comment: Wait, I'll edit my post and add the insert statement. :)

Comment: I ran your create table script, went into edit, and added 2 records, both of which auto incremented. (SQL 2014) But this should be no different in 2005....strange.

Comment: hmmm, I don't know what is the problem with my MS SQL 2005..

Comment: Hey :) I tried it in my SQL and it auto increments, I guess the error is my INSERT script

Comment: You're using "SET INDENTITY_INSERT ON" the only purpose for it is to manually enter values into identity field instead of letting the database to do it

Comment: Ok, I'll remove set identity insert and set identity off so the insert statement will only remain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this part

From

```
INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[TestTbl]
    ([id],[Agent_id]) VALUES ('','$agent')
```

To

```
INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[TestTbl]
    ([Agent_id]) VALUES ('$agent')
```

When it's auto increment, you don't' need to specify that in your `INSERT` statement.

Also do not `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` to `OFF` when you want to use auto increment feature of your table

[`SET IDENTITY_INSERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188059.aspx) allows explicit values to be inserted into the identity column of a table.

Your complete query

```
 if(isset($_POST['agentid'])){
    $agent = $_POST['agentid'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM [Test].[dbo].[TestTbl] WHERE [Agent_id] = '$agent'";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
      if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) !=0){
    echo "ID EXISTS";
       }else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[TestTbl]
    ([Agent_id]) VALUES ('$agent')";
    echo "Added";
}}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried it and got an error saying. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the insert statement. Do I need to make id as a primary key?

Comment: No need to. Make sure about this part `([Agent_id]) VALUES ('$agent')`. Both should be just 1 value as Id is identity and auto inserted.

Comment: Yeah, you probably left  ([id],[Agent_id])  rather than just ([Agent_id])

Comment: Ohh, I saw it already, my bad, forgot to remove the '  '..Thanks for the answer.. Problem Solved. Thanks for the comments!  :)